# How to set a pipeline variable that contains a regular expression as value

Tags: azure-devops, kubectl, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, configmap

I am trying assign a regular expression as a value to a variable in a **release pipeline** in Azure DevOps as follows:
[image]

`configmap.yaml` file references to this pipeline variable:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
data:
  ...
  VARIABLE_NAME: #{variable-name}#
```

Next, I clic "Create Release Button".
A stage task uses this variable through command

`kubectl apply -n namespace -f /path/to/my/configmap.yaml`

But it fails with next error:

`error validating data: ValidationError(ConfigMap.data.VARIABLE_NAME): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data: got "array", expected "string"`

I think release pipeline or kubectl confuse this reg exp string with an array. But is wrong

How assign correctly value of regular expressions to a pipeline release variable ?

Comment: how exactly are you replacing the variable `#{variable-name}#` in the configmap with pipeline variable?

Comment: Don't try to manipulate Kubernetes manifests with regular expressions. Use a templating system actually designed to work with Kubernetes, like Helm or Kustomize. You're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Sibtain with https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task/blob/master/ReplaceTokens/ReplaceTokensV4/README.md TASK

Comment: Ok, and does it gives any issues if you hardcode it without `#{variable-name}#`?